# pydrake URDF setting dynamic parameters

Tags: drake

I am having issues setting the dynamic properties of collisions in the URDF file.

I saw that the standard ode tags are used and there is also a new specific drake 
[drake github pull requeset](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/12464) xml tag.

Here is how I define the collision in my urdf. The object is a simple box.

```sh
<collision>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <geometry>
     <box size="0.85 0.85 2." />
  </geometry>
  <drake:drake>
     <drake:hydroelastic_resolution_hint value="1.3" />
     <drake:elastic_modulus value="1e8" />
     <drake:dissipation value="0.25" />
     <drake:mu_dynamic value="0.7" />
     <drake:mu_static value="0.7" />
  </drake:drake>
  <surface>
    <friction>
     <ode>
       <mu>0.6</mu>
       <mu2>0.6</mu2>
     </ode>
   </friction>
 </surface>
</collision>
```

The pydrake code is as follows:

```py
builder = DiagramBuilder()
plant, scene_graph = AddMultibodyPlantSceneGraph(builder, 0.001)
parser = Parser(plant)

peg_model_instance = Parser(plant).AddModelFromFile('square_peg.urdf')

plant.Finalize()

print('Collision Geometry properties for: {}'.format(peg_body.name()))
for collision_geometry in plant.GetCollisionGeometriesForBody(peg_body):
    const_proximity_properties = inspector.GetProximityProperties(collision_geometry)
    coulomb_friction = const_proximity_properties.GetProperty('material', 'coulomb_friction')
    print('Coulomb')
    print('static: {}'.format(coulomb_friction.static_friction()))
    print('dynamic: {}'.format(coulomb_friction.dynamic_friction()))
```

I retrieve the material properties and print them. The output is:

```sh
Collision Geometry properties for: peg_link
Coulomb
static: 1.0
dynamic: 1.0
```

It seems that there is an issue in parsing or I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely set properties from either SDF or URDF. I recommend browsing examples in Drake.

It is strange you decided to set the hydroelastic properites, for which we do have code but no examples. That model is currently under development and not fully supported. Unless you have very good reasons, I'd recommend you keep using the point contact solver.

In any case, the reason it didn't work for you is because it is not `<drake:drake>` but `<drake:proximity_properties>`. Unit tests are a good source for figuring out the available options, see [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/d24bc88e50e3a506cfcff98bed2f88350f34243e/multibody/parsing/test/detail_urdf_geometry_test.cc#L559).

The `<surface>` tag is not URDF and gets ignored, it is an SDF tag. That explains what it didn't work either. That's expected. I recommend reading the SDF specification docs and browsing through Drake example sdf files (a global search for `<surface>` will quickly reveal this tag only used in SDF files).

Withing URDF files you can also do:

```
<drake_compliance>
  <static_friction>0.8</static_friction>
  <dynamic_friction>0.3</dynamic_friction>
</drake_compliance>
```

All parsing options are thoroughly [documented here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/d24bc88e50e3a506cfcff98bed2f88350f34243e/multibody/parsing/detail_urdf_geometry.h#L171), though I realize not easily discoverable. I will file an issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I am sure everything is thoroughly documented in a unit test. It is however a bit hard to discover them given that we were not looking for examples in unit tests. But now we will start checking unit tests for documentation.

Comment: I know, sorry about that, it's work in progress. Based on this discussion I opened issue [13124](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/13124) to at least make these docs more discoverable.

Comment: thanks a lot. You might have to put up with some more obvious questions :) in the near future. We are not full blown software devs yet.

Comment: FTR the `<drake_comliance>` tag is due to be retired and the `<drake:proximity_properties>` specification of the frictions of coefficients are preferred. The fact that 0.7, 0.7 weren't returned is a bug. The friction coefficients are *not* hydroelastic specific.

Answer (score 0):

Wow!  You've found the parameters of the hydroelastic contact model, which is coming online but is not enabled by default yet.

The main contact model used by `MultibodyPlant` right now is a "Penalty method point contact" model.  It's documented quite thoroughly [here](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#mbp_penalty_method) (and the links that follow).  I haven't checked the parsers, but I believe the current status/recommendation is to set those parameters programmatically for the MBP, if the defaults are insufficient; I don't think they can be set in the urdf/sdf.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if understand correctly all material properties (for instance if we want steel or rubber objects) should be set programmatically. Would this be the case for non MultibodyPlant ? I think I will raise an issue in github, about the parsing.

Comment: Yes, we can set friction parameters in both URDF/SDF. However if we use the incorrect syntax parsing is ignored and default values (1.0) are used. See my detailed answer below.

Answer (score 0):

See accepted answer for how to set dynamic properties in code.
Below is code to change it programmatically.

```py
def copy_object_proximity_properties(const_proximity_properties, new_proximity_properties):
    for group_name in const_proximity_properties.GetGroupNames():
        properties = const_proximity_properties.GetPropertiesInGroup(group_name)
        for name in properties:
            if new_proximity_properties.HasProperty(group_name, name):
                continue
            new_proximity_properties.AddProperty(group_name, name, const_proximity_properties.GetProperty(group_name, name))


def set_rigid_body_coulomb_friction(scene_graph, plant, source_id, rigid_body, static_friction, dynamic_friction):
    new_proximity_properties = ProximityProperties()
    new_proximity_properties.AddProperty('material',
                                         'coulomb_friction',
                                         CoulombFriction(static_friction, dynamic_friction))

    geometry_id = plant.GetCollisionGeometriesForBody(rigid_body)[0]
    inspector = scene_graph.model_inspector()
    const_proximity_properties = inspector.GetProximityProperties(geometry_id)

    copy_object_proximity_properties(const_proximity_properties, new_proximity_properties)
    scene_graph.AssignRole(source_id, geometry_id, new_proximity_properties, RoleAssign.kReplace)
```